# DynamicJson does not deserialize arrays of "non-object" types correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, json, servicestack, deserialization

`DynamicJson.Deserialize("{\"arr\": [{\"key1\":1}, {\"key2\":2}]}")` works properly, but `DynamicJson.Deserialize("{\"arr\": [1, 2]}")`does not.

What is the proper way to correctly deserialize an array of a non-object type to a dynamic in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is to create a POCO that matches the shape of the JSON you're trying to deserialize, e.g:

```
var json = "{\"arr\": [1, 2]}";

public class Poco
{
    public List<string> Arr { get; set; }
}

var dto = json.FromJson<Poco>();
```

Otherwise you can use the [Dynamic JSON API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json) to parse the JSON dynamically, e.g:

```
string[] arr = JsonObject.Parse(json)
    .Get<string[]>("arr");
```